# pydantic: Using property.getter decorator for a field with an alias

Tags: python, types, fastapi, pydantic

*scroll all the way down for a tl;dr, I provide context which I think is important but is not directly relevant to the question asked*

### A bit of context

I'm in the making of an API for a webapp and some values are computed based on the values of others in a *pydantic* `BaseModel`. These are used for user validation, data serialization and definition of database (NoSQL) documents.

Specifically, I have nearly all resources inheriting from a `OwnedResource` class, which defines, amongst irrelevant other properties like creation/last-update dates:

- `object_key` -- The key of the object using a [nanoid](https://pypi.org/project/nanoid/) of length 6 with a custom alphabet
- `owner_key` -- This key references the user that owns that object -- a nanoid of length 10.
- `_key` -- this one is where I'm bumping into some problems, and I'll explain why.

So arangodb -- the database I'm using -- imposes `_key` as the name of the property by which resources are identified.

Since, in my webapp, all resources are only accessed by the users who created them, they can be identified in URLs with just the object's key (eg. `/subject/{object_key}`). However, as `_key` must be unique, I intend to construct the value of this field using `f"{owner_key}/{object_key}"`, to store the objects of every user in the database and potentially allow for cross-user resource sharing in the future.

The goal is to have the shortest **per-user** unique identifier, since the `owner_key` part of the full `_key` used to actually access and act upon the document stored in the database is always the same: the currently-logged-in user's `_key`.

### My attempt

My thought was then to define the `_key` field as a `@property`-decorated function in the class. However, Pydantic does not seem to register those as model fields.

Moreover, the attribute must actually be named `key` and use an alias (with `Field(... alias="_key"`), as [pydantic treats underscore-prefixed fields as internal and does not expose them](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/288).

Here is the definition of `OwnedResource`:

```py
class OwnedResource(BaseModel):
    """
    Base model for resources owned by users
    """

    object_key: ObjectBareKey = nanoid.generate(ID_CHARSET, OBJECT_KEY_LEN)
    owner_key: UserKey
    updated_at: Optional[datetime] = None
    created_at: datetime = datetime.now()

    @property
    def key(self) -> ObjectKey:
        return objectkey(self.owner_key)

    class Config:
        fields = {"key": "_key"} # [1]
```

[1] Since Field(..., alias="...") cannot be used, I use this property of the Config subclass (see [pydantic's documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/))

However, this does not work, as shown in the following example:

```py
@router.post("/subjects/")
def create_a_subject(subject: InSubject):
    print(subject.dict(by_alias=True))
```

with `InSubject` defining properties proper to `Subject`, and `Subject` being an empty class inheriting from both `InSubject` and `OwnedResource`:

```py
class InSubject(BaseModel):
    name: str
    color: Color
    weight: Union[PositiveFloat, Literal[0]] = 1.0
    goal: Primantissa # This is just a float constrained in a [0, 1] range
    room: str

class Subject(InSubject, OwnedResource):
    pass
```

When I perform a `POST /subjects/`, the following is printed in the console:

```py
{'name': 'string', 'color': Color('cyan', rgb=(0, 255, 255)), 'weight': 0, 'goal': 0.0, 'room': 'string'}
```

As you can see, `_key` or `key` are nowhere to be seen.

Please ask for details and clarification, I tried to make this as easy to understand as possible, but I'm not sure if this is clear enough.

### tl;dr

A context-less and more generic example without insightful context:

With the following class:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class SomeClass(BaseModel):
    
    spam: str

    @property
    def eggs(self) -> str:
        return self.spam + " bacon"

    class Config:
        fields = {"eggs": "_eggs"}
```

I would like the following to be true:

```py
a = SomeClass(spam="I like")
d = a.dict(by_alias=True)
d.get("_eggs") == "I like bacon"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can update to the newest version of Pydantic 2, which may be a bit of an ordeal honestly, there are some really nice new feature including support for properties like you are referring to. I recently updated and after some refactoring I have been happy with the newer version.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, computed_field
    
class SomeClass(BaseModel):
        
    spam: str
  
    @computed_field
    @property
    def eggs(self) -> str:
        return self.spam + " bacon" 

a = SomeClass(spam="I like")
a.model_dump()  # -> {'spam': 'I like', 'eggs': 'I like bacon'}
```

Answer (score 14):

Pydantic does not support serializing properties, there is an [issue](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/935) on GitHub requesting this feature.

Based on this [comment](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/935#issuecomment-641175527) by ludwig-weiss he suggests subclassing BaseModel and overriding the `dict` method to include the properties.

```py
class PropertyBaseModel(BaseModel):
    """
    Workaround for serializing properties with pydantic until
    https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/935
    is solved
    """
    @classmethod
    def get_properties(cls):
        return [prop for prop in dir(cls) if isinstance(getattr(cls, prop), property) and prop not in ("__values__", "fields")]

    def dict(
        self,
        *,
        include: Union['AbstractSetIntStr', 'MappingIntStrAny'] = None,
        exclude: Union['AbstractSetIntStr', 'MappingIntStrAny'] = None,
        by_alias: bool = False,
        skip_defaults: bool = None,
        exclude_unset: bool = False,
        exclude_defaults: bool = False,
        exclude_none: bool = False,
    ) -> 'DictStrAny':
        attribs = super().dict(
            include=include,
            exclude=exclude,
            by_alias=by_alias,
            skip_defaults=skip_defaults,
            exclude_unset=exclude_unset,
            exclude_defaults=exclude_defaults,
            exclude_none=exclude_none
        )
        props = self.get_properties()
        # Include and exclude properties
        if include:
            props = [prop for prop in props if prop in include]
        if exclude:
            props = [prop for prop in props if prop not in exclude]

        # Update the attribute dict with the properties
        if props:
            attribs.update({prop: getattr(self, prop) for prop in props})

        return attribs
```

Comment: Update: This is now supported in pydantic 2: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/main/docs/usage/computed_fields.md

Comment: Update: the docs are now at https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/computed_fields/

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to serialize your `_key` field using a [pydantic validator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#validate-always) with the `always` option set to True.

Using your example:

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator


class SomeClass(BaseModel):

    spam: str
    eggs: Optional[str] = Field(alias="_eggs")

    @validator("eggs", always=True)
    def set_eggs(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        """Set the eggs field based upon a spam value."""
        return v or values.get("spam") + " bacon"


a = SomeClass(spam="I like")
my_dictionary = a.dict(by_alias=True)
print(my_dictionary)
> {'spam': 'I like', '_eggs': 'I like bacon'}
print(my_dictionary.get("_eggs"))
> "I like bacon"
```

So to serialize your `_eggs` field, instead of appending a string, you'd insert your serialization function there and return the output of that.