# Fastapi how to convert string to list when calling get methos?

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, python-3.x, fastapi

I am using mysql database and it's doesn't support list if I stored sting like "apple","banana" in my mysql database then when using get method fastapi how to convert theme from string to list like ["apple","banana"]. I tried this but didn't work and also not getting the image fields until I remove  @property.

```
class Shop_page(BaseModel):
      product_title: str
      product_image: str
      class Config():
          orm_mode = True
      @property
      def product_image(self):
        return self.product_image.split(",")
```

here is my get method

```
@router.get("/shop_page", response_model=List[schemas.Shop_page],status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def create_variations(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
          parent_item = db.query(models.ParentProduct).all()
          return parent_item
```

my result look like now

```
[
  {
    "product_title": "DEMO PRODUCT",
    "product_image": "image1_url,image2_url"
  }
]
```

my expected result will be look like this

```
[
      {
        "product_title": "DEMO PRODUCT",
        "product_image": ["image1_url,image2_url"]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pydantic: Using property.getter decorator for a field with an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264888/pydantic-using-property-getter-decorator-for-a-field-with-an-alias)

Comment: sudden_appearance no this is't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [validators](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/) are for. But you need to define the schema the way you *actually* want it, not the way you receive it from your ORM. That means `product_image` should be annotated as a `list[str]` and your validator with `pre=True` will handle the case, if you try and initialize it with a string instead:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class ShopPage(BaseModel):
    product_title: str
    product_image: list[str]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

    @validator("product_image", pre=True)
    def split_urls(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            return v.split(",")
        return v


if __name__ == "__main__":
    class TestORM:
        product_title = "foo"
        product_image = "bar,baz"

    obj = ShopPage.from_orm(TestORM)
    print(obj.json(indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
{
  "product_title": "foo",
  "product_image": [
    "bar",
    "baz"
  ]
}
```

The advantage of the validator approach is that it will apply regardless of how you initialize `ShopPage` and can even apply during *assignment*, if you configure your model with `validate_assignment = True`. So even if you do `ShopPage(product_title="a", product_image="b,c")`, you'll get the `product_image` as a list.

Answer (score 0):

[Pydantic does not support @property decorator serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264888/pydantic-using-property-getter-decorator-for-a-field-with-an-alias)

And I think you can just override `from_orm` method as follows:

```
from typing import Type, Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class ShopPage(BaseModel):
    product_title: str
    product_image: list

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
    
    @classmethod
    def from_orm(cls: Type['Model'], obj: Any):
        if hasattr(obj, "product_image") and isinstance(obj.product_image, str):
            obj.product_image = obj.product_image.split(",")

        return super().from_orm(obj)
```

Comment: getting this error `Shop_page.from_orm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj' (type=type_error)`

Comment: Yeah, that is because the `@classmethod` decorator is missing. Also this solution only addresses the specific `from_orm` situation. A better solution is a custom validator because that will work regardless of how you initialize your model. Unfortunately, the annotations here are also wrong/incomplete.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg thanks for noting of missing `@classmethod`. This solution provides instant mapping to list before creating instance of pydantic object. An option using @validator will still be dealing with string and if there are other validators should be considering type mutations as well